# how to check if input is clear (react redux)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

im trying to create a discord clone, and when i hit enter when the input is empty it shows an empty message, any idea how to prevent that from happening? im new to react, firebase and redux.

```
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
const channelId = useSelector(selectChannelId);
const channelName = useSelector(selectChannelName);
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (channelId) {

        db.collection('channels')
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
    }
}, [channelId])
```

const sendMessage = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
db.collection('channels').doc(channelId).collection('messages').add({
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    message: input,
    user: user,

    
});
setInput('')
```

}

```
return (
    <div className="chat">
        <ChatHeader channelName={channelName}/>

        <div className="chat__messages">
            {messages.map((message) => (
                <Message 
                timestamp={message.timestamp}
                message={message.message}
                user={message.user}
                />
            ))}
        </div>

        <div className="chat__input">
            <AddCircleIcon fontSize="large"/>
            <form>
                <input 
                    id="input"
                    value={input} 
                    disabled={!channelId}
                    onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} 
                    placeholder={`Message #${channelName}`}
                />

                <button onClick={sendMessage} className="chat__inputButton" type="submit">
                    Send Message
                </button>
            </form>
            <div className="chat__inputIcons">
                <CardGiftcardIcon fontSize="large"/>
                <GifIcon fontSize="large"/>
                <EmojiEmotionsIcon fontSize="large"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Chat

Comment: What have you tried to do to prevent that so far?

Comment: i tried a lot but it didnt work, and i mean really a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prevent your submit function from calling firebase if your input is empty.

```
const sendMessage = (e) => { 
 e.preventDefault();
 if (input.length <= 0) return; // This will end the function here if your input is empty

 db.collection('channels').doc(channelId).collection('messages').add({
     timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
     message: input,
     user: user,       
 });
 setInput('')
}
```

Comment: Yes, but must importantly: Did you understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if is some value in it. Empty string is falsable so you can check it in one line.

```
<input onChange={e => e.target.value && setInput(e.target.value)}/
```

But in your case probably you send your form on enter. So you can block sending form with empty input by setting validation pattern

```
<input pattenr=".+" />
```

or make validation in sumbmit function.